# RAML Trait wrapping a response object (for defining REST API)

Tags: rest, api, api-design, raml

Using RAML, I am trying to create an envelop that multiple APIs can use to wrap response. That is, a generic response envelop.

I have come up with this:

```
title: Response Envelop
version: 1.0

uses:
  another: ./another.raml

traits:
  responseEnvelope:
    usage: This trait should be used to wrap any response object
    body:
      application/json:
        type: object
        properties:
          metadata:
            type: another.AType
          responseObjectToWrap:
            type: any
          message:
            type: another.BType
```

I am having difficulty defining the `responseObjectToWrap` part above. That is the type that will be wrapped by the response envelop. Does `type: any` work?

Also, how do I use this trait in a API? For example, if I want to wrap a type `NewType` using this envelop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable for the type '<>':

```
responseEnvelope:
        usage: This trait should be used to wrap any response object
        body:
          application/json:
            type: object
            properties:
              metadata:
              responseObjectToWrap:
                type: <<typeName>>
              message:
```

And then pass that type when you define the trait on your resource:

```
/myResource:
  post:
    is: { responseEnvelope: {  typeName : MyCustomType } }
```

Full example:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: Response Envelop
version: 1.0

traits:
  responseEnvelope:
    usage: This trait should be used to wrap any response object
    body:
      application/json:
        type: object
        properties:
          metadata:
          responseObjectToWrap:
            type: <<typeName>>
          message:


types:
  NewType:
    properties:
      bla: 

/myResource:
  post:
    is: { responseEnvelope: {  typeName : NewType } }
```

**Updated. Originally posted to wrong question accidentally and deleted instantaneously by mods for being a duplicate**